# multiple boxplots in one chart in C#

Tags: c#, charts, boxplot, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm trying to figure out how to get c# to put in more than one boxplot in a chart. There's not much help in the internet as soon as it comes to c# instead of R or python. So I'm asking: What did I do wrong or miss in this code?

```
   private void on_boxplot(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                  
        List<String> xValue = new List<String> { "Ala (A)", "Arg (R)", "Asn (N)", "Asp (D)", "Cys (C)", "Gln (Q)", "Glu (E)", "Gly (G)", "His (H)", "Ile (I)", "Leu (L)", "Lys (K)", "Met (M)", "Phe (F)", "Pro (P)", "Ser (S)", "Thr (T)", "Trp (W)", "Tyr (Y)", "Val (V)", "Pyl (O)", "Sec (U)" };
        Chart Chart = new Chart();
        Chart.chart_main.Series.Clear();
        Chart.chart_main.Series.Add("BoxPlotSeries");
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < xValue.Count; i++)
        {
            Chart.chart_main.Series.Add(xValue[i]); 
        }

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < DYL; i++)
        {
            if (Data[i, 0] == null) break;
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[0]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[0]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[1]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[1]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[2]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[2]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[3]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[3]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[4]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[4]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[5]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[5]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[6]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[6]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[7]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[7]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[8]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[8]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[9]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[9]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[10]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[10]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[11]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[11]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[12]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[12]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[13]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[13]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[14]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[14]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[15]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[15]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[16]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[16]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[17]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[17]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[18]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[18]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[19]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[19]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[20]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[20]));
            Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[21]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[21]));     
        }

        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotSeries"] = xValue[0];

        Chart.chart_main.ChartAreas.Add("BoxPlot");
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"].ChartArea = "BoxPlot";

        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotWhiskerPercentile"] = "0";
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotPercentile"] = "25";
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotShowAverage"] = "true";
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotShowMedian"] = "true";
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotShowUnusualValues"] = "true";
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["MaxPixelPointWidth"] = "15";
        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"].BorderWidth = 2;
        Chart.Show();

    }

    private Double boxplot_helper(Int32 i, Int32 slot)
    {
        String Santas = Data[i, slot].Replace('.', ',').TrimEnd('%').Trim();
        Double LittleHelper = Convert.ToDouble(Santas);
        return LittleHelper;

    }
```

[image]

Above is the outcome but I'd like 22 of those. Anyone happen to have any kind of idea how to solve this?

Comment: have you found a way to sort these series?

Comment: I want all the series to be sorted ascending, on the basis of median.

Comment: Guess you have to presort it first because what you see there is just a png. Median is very easy to get.

Comment: yes, thats how I solved it in the meanwhile. Have to sort the series names before I assign them to boxplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple boxplots as

```
Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotSeries"] = string.Join(";", xValue);
```

Comment: Worked like a bliss. :)

Comment: can I somehow sort these series?

Answer (score 2):

One might be interested in what I did:

```
        List<String> Series = new List<String>();
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        {
            Series.Add(xValue[i]);
        }
        String Helper = String.Join("; ", Series);

        Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotSeries"] = Helper;
```

And the outcome:

[image]

Comment: Can possible to add X axis label with string value for box plot?