# Axis labels on boxplot

Tags: c#, charts, boxplot

What I got is this:

[image]

But I'd like to have the series name under each boxplot. Any way this can be done?

Boxplot charting with C# is quite frustrating.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this code to the code of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731793/).

```
Chart.chart_main.ChartAreas["BoxPlot"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;

for (int i = 0; i < xValue.Count; i++)
{
    Chart.chart_main.ChartAreas["BoxPlot"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add((i + 1)* 2d, 0.0, xValue[i]);
}
```

Comment: Had that one solved about 2 hrs after posting with this:for (Int32 i = 0; i < 22; i++)
            {
                Chart.chart_main.ChartAreas["BoxPlot"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i + 0.5, i + 1.5, xValue[i]); 
            }